# RFID , FingerPrint ASP.NET c#

Tags: asp.net, fingerprint, rfid

I need to connect a fingerprint to an ASP.NET MVC Application , when a person put his finger the asp.net mvc capture the response from the device and log the result in a database.

Any idea please ?

Thanks

Comment: can you share how you are planning on capturing the fingerprints. Fingerprint scanners are not unique and some devices comes with their own sdk. I know companies like  [dynasoft](https://www.dynamsoft.com/Products/.Net-TWAIN-Scanner.aspx) and [bayometric](https://www.bayometric.com/griaule-grfinger-sdk-fingerprint-recognition-software/) sell universal sdk with api's for all kind of scanner. the alternative would be to write your own.

Comment: Hello, i have a turnstile work with a fingerprint , and i have an ASP.NET MVC app hosted in Azure , this app store a list of employees i want  to add a new feature : affect to each employee an id that's is related to his fingerprint when he come to the office and pass throw the turnslite i capture this and i log the date and hour into the database in Azure. for the moment i think i need to develop a new  software that well be installed in the computer related to the turnslite and call a webapi from the asp.net mvc to do the work

Comment: it sounds like it's for internal use and you have not purchased the fingerprint scanners yet. If this is the case, just pick one model that comes with an SDK, like max_dev suggested.